# group a set of records by date in teradata

Tags: sql, date, grouping, teradata

Currently I have data in a table as shown below:

```
date        id   value
1-Jan-13    1    100
2-Jan-13    1    100
3-Jan-13    1    100
4-Jan-13    1    200
5-Jan-13    1    200
6-Jan-13    1    100
7-Jan-13    1    100
```

I am trying to group the records based on the id and val and version records with startdate and end date .

Desired output:

```
start date  end date    id   value
1-Jan-13    3-Jan-13    1    100
4-Jan-13    5-Jan-13    1    200
6-Jan-13    7-Jan-13    1    100
```

Comment: What exactly is your grouping criteria? As I see the first group is of three days and the other two are of two days. How is it?

Comment: im grouping based on both id and value. so that i ll be able to create a VERSION out of it..

Comment: Perhaps this question gives you a clue- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13037749/crystal-reports-need-to-group-by-derived-date-range

Comment: im not pretty sure on how it works with teradata :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in Teradata but you most likely, since windowing functions are supported (specifically [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_14_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_111A/Ordered_Analytical_Functions.083.162.html#ww1457049)),  be able to do something like this

```
SELECT MIN(date) start_date, MAX(date) end_date, id, value
  FROM
(
  SELECT date, id, value,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) -
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, value ORDER BY date) island
    FROM table1
) q
 GROUP BY id, value, island 
 ORDER BY start_date, end_date
```

Sample output:

```
| START_DATE |   END_DATE | ID | VALUE |
|------------|------------|----|-------|
| 2013-01-01 | 2013-01-03 |  1 |   100 |
| 2013-01-04 | 2013-01-05 |  1 |   200 |
| 2013-01-06 | 2013-01-07 |  1 |   100 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fc5c/4)** demo (*It's a SQL Server demo, but should work as expected in Teradata*)

Comment: Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

The ROW_NUMBER version can be further simplified: [modified SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fc5c/12)

For Teradata:

```
SELECT 
   id,val,MIN(dt),MAX(dt)
FROM
 (
   SELECT
      id,val,dt,
      dt - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY val, dt) AS dummy
   FROM table1
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY 1,2,dummy
```

And there are some hardly known functions in TD13.10 for processing time series data:

```
WITH cte(id,val,pd) AS 
 (
   SELECT id, val, PERIOD(dt, dt+1) AS pd
   FROM table1
 )
SELECT
   id, val,
   BEGIN(pd) AS start_dt,
   LAST(pd) AS end_dt
FROM
   TABLE (TD_NORMALIZE_MEET
           (NEW VARIANT_TYPE(cte.id,cte.val)
           ,cte.pd)
   RETURNS (id INTEGER
           ,val INTEGER
           ,pd PERIOD(DATE)
           ,Nrm_Count INTEGER)
   HASH BY id
   LOCAL ORDER BY id, val, pd
   ) A 
ORDER BY start_dt, end_dt
```